# PhotonView.RPC not called under PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.IsMasterClient

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I'd like to make the master client execute the news updates code, and other clients receive the updates message from the master client, but I met a weird problem when I put `PhotonView.RPC()` within `if (!PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.IsMasterClient)`

This is the news updates code executed only by the master client:

```
      if (PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.IsMasterClient)
      {
        if (currentItem < news.newsList.Count)
        {
            timeGap = TimeManager.globalSec - pubTime;
            if (timeGap >= 2)
            {
                pubTime = TimeManager.globalSec;
                if (page[currentPage].Count < 4)
                {
                    page[currentPage].Add(news.newsList[currentItem]);

                    hlTitle.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = news.newsList[currentItem].newsTitle;
                    hlContent.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = news.newsList[currentItem].newsContent;

                    if (currentPage == 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < page[currentPage].Count; i++)
                        {
                            newsItems[i].GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = page[currentPage][i].newsTitle;
                        }
                    }
                    currentItem++;
                }
                else
                {
                    page.Add(new List<NewsIndex>());
                    pageSum++;
                }
            }
            NewsCount(currentItem, pageSum);
            print(itemSum);
            print(pageSum)
        }
    }
```

Code in Punrpc:

```
[PunRPC]
void NewsCount(int newsNum, int pageNum)
{
    itemSum = newsNum;
    pageSum = pageNum;
}
```

Other clients receive message from master client:

```
if (!PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.IsMasterClient) {
   view.RPC("NewsCount", RpcTarget.All, itemSum, pageSum);
   print(itemSum);
   print(pageSum);
}
```

Now the problem is that it can print out numbers but is constantly 0 and 1, which means the view.RPC() doesn't work at all.

[Console log in master client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0otH.png)

[Console log in other clients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdIqb.png)

Answer (score 0):

to be honest I'm a bit confused. You say

> Other clients receive message from master client

but **no!** In your code all the **non-master** clients are **sending** an RPC, not receiving.

And on the other hand I don't see the master client sending anything, he is rather directly calling `NewsCount` which makes this method be executed only locally for the master client but not actually send as an RPC to other clients!

So what happens is that all your non-master clients send their own `0` and `1` to everyone else since they never actually calculate these they never change. It doesn't affect the master client since he always calculates and prints his own values.

I can only guess but if I understanding you correctly you actually rather want to send the calculated values from the master client to everyone else.

So I think what you rather wanted to do is

```
    ...
    if (PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.IsMasterClient)
    {
        if (currentItem < news.newsList.Count)
        {
            ......

            view.RPC(namof(NewsCount), RpcTarget.AllBuffered, currentItem, pageSum);
        }
    }
    ...
    
[PunRPC]
void NewsCount(int newsNum, int pageNum)
{
    itemSum = newsNum;
    pageSum = pageNum;

    print($"new {nameof(itemSum)}={itemSum}");
    print($"new {nameof(pageSum)}={pageSum}");
}
```